# Eclipse ignoring the CLASSPATH variable?

Tags: java, classpath, environment-variables

I had the idea any java application would look up the `CLASSPATH` variable to check for classes at runtime.

But that does not seem to be the case, as a application I'm running from Eclipse. In which concrete situations is the `CLASSPATH` variable used, then? How can I make sure Eclipse always makes use of my `CLASSPATH` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLASSPATH variable is used when the java (or javaw) command is launched without the -classpath or -jar or -cp option. But Eclipse follows best practices, and always uses these options.

IMHO, you should NEVER rely on CLASSPATH. Always specify the classpath explicitely, in the command line options. It's quite rare to want ALL your java programs to share the same libraries. That's why the CLASSPATH global environment variable is a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting. I've never noticed that the CLASSPATH variable was being ignored when setting the -cp option. Thanks. ps: I have also shared your concerns about the CLASSPATH environment variable. I was just curious. It does have its place in some cases, though (for instance, for aspectrt.jar, which will be the same for all the java running programs in your system, at least, most of times).